# How to close div only if it's shown

Tags: jquery

i display a div and close it by click to close button. Additional the modal should hide if a click is outside from this. I do this all with this code

```
$('.openModal').on('click', function() {  $('#Modal').slideToggle(1000);});


$('.close').on('click', function() {  $('#Modal').slideToggle(600); });

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
$(window).click(function(e) {
        $('#Modal').slideToggle(600); 
});
```

Now the last function will run everytime if there is a click on the website. Thats not fine. How i can run this function only if the modal/div is already displayed?

Try with this won't work

```
if($('#Modal').is(':visible')){ $(window).click(function(e) {
            $('#Modal').slideToggle(600); 
      }); }
```

Comment: why you not just use `slideUp()` instead of `slideToggle()` on window click .. and you need to use `e.stopPropagation()` inside the click event for the `#Modal`

Comment: Why not check inside the ```$(window).click function if the element with the .openModal class Is shown?

Comment: why slideUp is better than toggle?

Comment: @RainerS its not about better or not .. its depending on the case of every code  .. and in your case `slideToggle()` will fire on every time you click the document.. so your modal will keep open and hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok a lot of information you'll need to know .. but not all of those you'll need in this case

**1st:** to check if element visible or not

```
if($(el).is(':visible'))
```

**2nd:** you can use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` instead of `slideToggle()`;

**3rd** to prevent the click event in the nested element

```
$(el).on('click' , function(e){
   e.preventPropagation()
})
```

**4th** to skip the Modal from `$(window)` click or `$(document)` click .. you can use the next function

```
function OnwindowClick(elem , action){
    $(document).on('click',function(e){
        if (!$(elem).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && $(elem).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            action();
        }
    });
}
```

and use this function like

```
OnwindowClick('#Modal', function(){
   $('#Modal').slideUp(600);
});
```

> **Note:** In your case here I think you'll need to use just the #4th one

Comment: thank for explain me, ive update the code with a trie to hide if its visible, could you tell me why it wont work? You 4th solution has the same problem like my first way. The function called up on every click (if i'm wright)

Comment: @RainerS the if statement inside the click not outside it

Comment: sorry maybe im to tierd, could you show me what i do wrong?

Comment: @RainerS `$(document).on('click' , function(){   if($('#Modal').is(':visible')){  //code here  }  })`  the if statement should be inside the click event not outside it .. BUT as I said in my answer .. you'll need the #4th point in my answer

Comment: @RainerS the document click will fire even when click on the `#Modal` because of that you'll need the point number #4 to prevent this from happening

Comment: mmh, i trie your 4th way and my code, nothing works, the modal wipes up and immediately out, maybe its caused of the delay of the animationtime?